# Forcing fractional parts to be less than $\varepsilon$ simultaneously

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis

**Edit**: For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\langle x \rangle $ denote the unique number in $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ s.t. $x - \langle x \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose that we have $x_1, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, given $\varepsilon >0$, does there necessarily exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$|\langle kx_i \rangle| < \varepsilon$$

for every $i$?

The original problem, which I read incorrectly from where I was working on it (the same question with $\langle x \rangle = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ the standard fractional part), was disproved by the counterexample given by Haran.

Comment: Have you tried using the Pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @Haran I may have missed something vast, but I don't see how that applies here.

Comment: Well, the problem statement does not seem true in general, what if you take $x_1 = \alpha$ and $x_2 = 1 - \alpha$ where $\alpha \in [0, 1)$ is irrational?

Comment: @Haran If it's not true, then how would the pigeonhole principle help? I understand your counterexample now though.

Comment: The purpose of me leaving comments instead of writing out a full answer is to give you hints so that you can solve the problem yourself as opposed to me solving it for you. This will be much more beneficial to you. Anyways, the point I am making is that the problem statement does not seem true (because of my comment about taking $x_1 = \alpha$ and $x_2 = 1 - \alpha$, do you see why this would be a problem?). However, you can salvage the problem by trying to see if you can make the distance to the closest integer less than $\epsilon$. Try to apply the Pigeonhole principle here.

Comment: @Haran I agree that hints are more "beneficial" than solutions, but providing a hint which would not work for the question I asked (without any further explanation) is surely less beneficial than no hint, so my point is that your first comment surely could have been clearer. Thank you for elaborating though.

Comment: For the "salvaged" problem, I think I see the pigeonhole argument with $(\frac1\epsilon)^n$ bins.

Comment: @Karl That's right! I apologize for any confusion with the first comment. That was supposed to be a hint to the salvaged problem.

Comment: Follow up problem: Is the original problem true if we add the extra condition that the $x_i$'s are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write an answer to my question, since others have opted not to.

Let $\frac{3}{N} < \varepsilon$ and imagine $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ as being tiled by $N$ disjoint intervals of width $\frac{1}{N}$. For every value of $k$, each $x_i$ lands in one of these intervals. But there are infinitely many choices of $k$ and only $N^n$ choices of intervals for $(\langle kx_i\rangle)$, so by the pigeonhole principle, $\exists k_1 < k_2$ s.t. $\langle k_1 x_i \rangle$ is in the same interval as $\langle k_2 x_i \rangle$ for each $i$. Then, $k = k_2 - k_1$ is sufficient for $| \langle kx_i \rangle | < \varepsilon$ for every $i$.